# In the local environment, the result value and the dataflow result values are different

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

Here is my input data.

ㅡ.Input(Local)

```
'Iot,c c++ python,2015',
'Web,java spring,2016',
'Iot,c c++ spring,2017',
'Iot,c c++ spring,2017',
```

This is the result of running apache-beam in a local environment.

ㅡ.Outout(Local)

```
Iot,2015,c,1
Iot,2015,c++,1
Iot,2015,python,1
Iot,2017,c,2
Iot,2017,c++,2
Iot,2017,spring,2
Web,2016,java,1
Web,2016,spring,1
```

However, when I run the google-cloud-platform dataflow and put it in a bucket, the results are different.

ㅡ. Storage(Bucket)

```
Web,2016,java,1
Web,2016,spring,1
Iot,2015,c,1
Iot,2015,c++,1
Iot,2015,python,1
Iot,2017,c,1
Iot,2017,c++,1
Iot,2017,spring,1
Iot,2017,c,1
Iot,2017,c++,1
Iot,2017,spring,1
```

Here is my code.

ㅡ. Code

```
#apache_beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam as beam

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    project='project-id',
    runner='dataflow',
    temp_location='bucket-location'
)
def pardo_dofn_methods(test=None):
    import apache_beam as beam


    class split_category_advanced(beam.DoFn):
      def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.k = 1
        self.pre_processing = []
        self.window = beam.window.GlobalWindow()
        self.year_dict = {}
        self.category_index = 0
        self.language_index = 1
        self.year_index = 2;
        self.result = []

      def setup(self):
          print('setup')

      def start_bundle(self):
          print('start_bundle')

      def finish_bundle(self):
          
          print('finish_bundle')
          for ppc_index in range(len(self.pre_processing)) :
              if self.category_index == 0 or self.category_index%3 == 0 :
                  if self.pre_processing[self.category_index] not in self.year_dict :
                          self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]] = {}

          
          if ppc_index + 2 == 2 or ppc_index + 2 == self.year_index :
              # { category : { year : {} } }
              if self.pre_processing[self.year_index] not in self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]] :
                     self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]][self.pre_processing[self.year_index]] = {}
              # { category : { year : c : { }, c++ : { }, java : { }}}
              language = self.pre_processing[self.year_index-1].split(' ')

              for lang_index in range(len(language)) :
                    if language[lang_index] not in self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]][self.pre_processing[self.year_index]] :
                      self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]][self.pre_processing[self.year_index]][language[lang_index]] = 1
                    else :
                        self.year_dict[self.pre_processing[self.category_index]][self.pre_processing[self.year_index]][
                            language[lang_index]] += 1
              self.year_index = self.year_index + 3
          self.category_index = self.category_index + 1

      csvFormat = ''
      for category, nested in self.year_dict.items() :
          for year in nested :
              for language in nested[year] :
                csvFormat+= (category+","+str(year)+","+language+","+str(nested[year][language]))+"\n"
                print(csvFormat)

      yield beam.utils.windowed_value.WindowedValue(
          value=csvFormat,
          #value = self.pre_processing,
          timestamp=0,
          windows=[self.window],
      )

  def process(self, text):
    for word in text.split(self.delimiter):
        self.pre_processing.append(word)
    print(self.pre_processing)

#with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  results = (
      pipeline
      | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
          'Iot,c c++ python,2015',
          'Web,java spring,2016',
          'Iot,c c++ spring,2017',
          'Iot,c c++ spring,2017',
  ])
      | 'Split category advanced' >> beam.ParDo(split_category_advanced(','))
      | 'Save' >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText("bucket-location")
      | beam.Map(print) \
  )
   if test:
       return test(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pardo_dofn_methods_basic()
```

Code for executing simple word counting.
CSV column has an [ category, year, language, count ]
e.g) IoT, 2015, c, 1

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting different output is because of parallelism. When using `DataflowRunner`, operations run as parallel as possible. Since you are using a ParDo to count, when element `Iot,c c++ spring,2017` goes to two different workers, the count doesn't happen as you want (you are counting in the ParDo).

You need to use Combiners ([4.2.4](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms))

Here you have an easy example of what you want to do:

```
    def generate_kvs(element, csv_delimiter=',', field_delimiter=' '):
        splitted = element.split(csv_delimiter)
        fields = splitted[1].split(field_delimiter)

        # final key to count is (Source, year, language)
        return [(f"{splitted[0]}, {splitted[2]}, {x}", 1) for x in fields]


    p = beam.Pipeline()

    elements = ['Iot,c c++ python,2015',
              'Web,java spring,2016',
              'Iot,c c++ spring,2017',
              'Iot,c c++ spring,2017']

    (p | Create(elements)
       | beam.ParDo(generate_kvs)
       | beam.combiners.Count.PerKey()
       | "Format" >> Map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}, {x[1]}")
       | Map(print))

    p.run()
```

This would output the result you want no matter the distribution you get of elements across workers.

Note the idea of Apache Beam is to parallelise as much as possible and, in order to aggregate, you need Combiners

I would recommend you to check some [wordcounts examples](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples) so you get the hang of the combiners

**EDIT**

Clarification on Combiners:

ParDo is a operation that happens in a element to element basis. It takes one element, makes some operations and sends the output to the next PTransform. When you need to do aggregate data (count elements, sum values, join sentences...), element wise operations don't work, you need something that takes a PCollection (i.e., many elements with a logic) and outputs something. This is where the combiners come in, they perform operations in a PCollection basis, which can be made across workers (part of the Map-Reduce operations)

In your example, you were using a Class parameter to store the count in the ParDo, so when a element went through it, it would change the parameter within the class. This would work when all elements go through the same worker, since the Class is "created" in a worker basis (i.e., they don't share states), but when there are more workers, the count (with the ParDo) is going to happen in each worker separately

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I read the document and I don't know exactly what the role of the combiner is. Can you give me a little more advice?

Comment: edited my answer, let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: Thank you so much for writing in detail. I got it. Perfectly.